# Decrypting SQL Server 2012 user password with windows administrative access?

Tags: windows, encryption, sql-server-2012, passwords

I have SQL Server 2012 with a database which has a user called 'basiclogin'

I can connect to this database with administrator credentials because im a windows admin on the machine.

Is there any way to decrypt the password of the basiclogin user?

Comment: You can't retrieve the password, but you can change it. It would be a terrible security design if it was possible to retrieve passwords.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Ya i know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no as Dragonthoughts already told you, you can only reset/change the password. This is just Windows security by design. 
Password are hashed like in any other system these days, only a match on that hash would result as a successful login, for which of course you need the password.

Comment: alright. I guess ill just have to brute force it and hope its some shitty password.